# Mock JS object in tests on browser platform

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutter-web-browser, flutter-js

I have this simplified dart file using `dart:js`:

(`dataLayer` is used for Google tags, if that's any help)

```dart
@JS()
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('dataLayer.push')
external void _push(data);

class Manager {
  void pushEvent(String event) {
    _push(event);
  }
}
```

On the web, it runs correctly and the `dataLayer` object is being created in a script in the `web/index.html` file.

---

I am trying to write a test about it. I would like to verify `dataLayer.push` is being called with the correct parameters.

I run my test with the command

```
flutter test --platform chrome
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

Is it possible to create a dummy `dataLayer` variable (and maybe have the hand on it to record the calls to the method `.push()`)? If yes, how?

Here is my attempt:

```dart
@TestOn('browser')

import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'my_project/my_file.dart';

class _DataLayer {
  void push(dynamic data) {}
}

@JS('dataLayer')
final dataLayer = _DataLayer();

void main() {
  test('It should push the event', () {
    Manager().pushEvent('myEvent');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it would be to load and use a custom HTML file during the tests where you can include a script to create the js variables you need.

Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/dart-lang/test#running-tests-with-custom-html) of the package [`test`](https://pub.dev/packages/test).

If your test file name is `folder/my_test.dart`, then you can create a html file named (`folder/my_test.html`):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Custom HTML file title</title>
  <link rel="x-dart-test" href="my_test.dart">
  <script src="packages/test/dart.js"></script>
  <script>
    window['dataLayer'] = [];
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72135177/12066144) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851181/load-custom-html-on-browser-tests).

and then you can run

```
dart test --platform chrome
```

---

However, this is only supported with `dart test` and not `flutter test`, see [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101916). In it, they recommend writing an integration test instead.