# How to injest javascript in

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutter-web-browser

I'm working on a Flutter web project. The `web/index.html` file is injecting a JavaScript script which could be simplified as:

```html
<script>
  window['dataLayer'] = [];
</script>
```

So in my flutter code, I can do:

```dart
@JS()
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('dataLayer.push')
external void push(data);

push(myData);
```

to push `myData` in the `window.dataLayer` array.

However, in the tests, when I'm running

```
flutter test --platform chrome
```

I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

when I call

```dart
push(myData);
```

because `window['dataLayer']` has never been created.

---

How can I inject some javascript scripts the same way I can do in the `index.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to load a custom HTML file while running the tests, see [the instructions](https://github.com/dart-lang/test#running-tests-with-custom-html) of the package [`test`](https://pub.dev/packages/test).

If your test file name is `folder/my_test.dart`, then you can create a html file named (`folder/my_test.html`):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Custom HTML file title</title>
  <link rel="x-dart-test" href="my_test.dart">
  <script src="packages/test/dart.js"></script>
  <script>
    window['dataLayer'] = [];
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851181/load-custom-html-on-browser-tests).

and then you can run

```
dart test --platform chrome
```

---

However, this is only supported with `dart test` and not `flutter test`, see [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101916). In it, they recommend writing an integration test instead.